# convert the columns into Horizontal PIVOT

Tags: excel, unix, awk, vba

I have 3 column file with ID,name and value .

```
1,Brand,sports
1,Color,White
1,Gender,Male
1,Logo,yes
1,width,10
4,Brand,Running
4,width,12
4,Fits,Lose
3,catgegory,shoe
3,Color,blue
3,Color,white
3,primarycolor,blue
5,size,M
5,Brand,Sports
5,Brand,Running
```

I'm trying to convert this into a horizontal format based on the column 1 and column 2.

It's similar to the Pivot table with text values printed, it can't be done using Excel pivot it will allow only sum/count of values.

Can this be generated in UNIX?

```
,Brand,Color,Gender,Logo,width,Fits,catgegory,primarycolor,size
1,sports,White,Male,yes,10,,,,
4,Running,,,,12,Lose,,,
3,,blue/white,,,,,shoe,blue,
5,Sports/Running,,,,,,,,M
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat data.txt 
1,Brand,sports
1,Color,White
1,Gender,Male
1,Logo,yes
1,width,10
4,Brand,Running
4,width,12
4,Fits,Lose
3,catgegory,shoe
3,Color,blue
3,primarycolor,blue
5,size,M
5,Brand,Running
```

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat pivot.awk 
{   
     id=$1; name=$2; value=$3
     ids[id]; 
     # this is to retain order
     if(!(name in tmp)){ tmp[name]; names[++c]=name; }
     values[id,name] = value
}
END {
     # comment below line if you hide "id"
     printf "id"

     for (name in names) {
         printf "%s%s",OFS,names[name]
     }
     print ""
     for (id in ids) {
         printf "%s",id
         for (name in names) {
             printf "%s%s",OFS,values[id,names[name]]
         } print ""
     }
}
```

**Execution and Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, -f pivot.awk data.txt 
id,Brand,Color,Gender,Logo,width,Fits,catgegory,primarycolor,size
1,sports,White,Male,yes,10,,,,
3,,blue,,,,,shoe,blue,
4,Running,,,,12,Lose,,,
5,Running,,,,,,,,M
```

**This produces o/p same as expected o/p including order**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat pivot_with_order.awk 
{   
     id=$1; name=$2; value=$3

     # this is to retain order
     if(!(id in itmp)){ itmp[id]; ids[++i]=id; } 
     if(!(name in tmp)){ tmp[name]; names[++c]=name; }

     values[id,name] = value
}
END {
     # uncomment below line if you want to display "id"
     # printf "id"

     for (name in names) {
         printf "%s%s",OFS,names[name]
     }
     print ""
     for (id in ids) {
         printf "%s",ids[id]
         for (name in names) {
             printf "%s%s",OFS,values[ids[id],names[name]]
         } print ""
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, -f pivot_with_order.awk data.txt 
,Brand,Color,Gender,Logo,width,Fits,catgegory,primarycolor,size
1,sports,White,Male,yes,10,,,,
4,Running,,,,12,Lose,,,
3,,blue,,,,,shoe,blue,
5,Running,,,,,,,,M
```

Comment: Thanks alot Akshay, i will check this one soon.

Comment: Suppose if i have differnt values for the same filed.like below, how can i change the script @akshay Hegde

5,Brand,Running
5,Brand,Running1

Output:
5,Running/Running1,,,,,,,,M

Comment: Sorry i have modified the question to include duplicate Scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA:

```
Sub Pivot()

    Dim rngData, rngOut, r, c, dR, dC
    Set dR = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dC = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C2") '<< first row of input
    Set rngOut = ActiveSheet.Range("G2")     '<< where to put output

    Do While Application.CountA(rngData) > 0
        r = rngData(1)
        c = rngData(2)
        If Not dR.exists(r) Then
            dR.Add r, dR.Count + 1
            rngOut.Offset(dR.Count, 0) = r
        End If
        If Not dC.exists(c) Then
            dC.Add c, dC.Count + 1
            rngOut.Offset(0, dC.Count) = c
        End If

        With rngOut.Offset(dR(r), dC(c))
            'if already has a value, add a newline separator
            .Value = .Value & IIf(.Value <> "", vbLf, "") & rngData(3)
        End With
        Set rngData = rngData.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.7**

Assuming that `list.csv` is:

```
1,Brand,sports
1,Color,White
1,Gender,Male
1,Logo,yes
1,width,10
4,Brand,Running
4,width,12
4,Fits,Lose
3,catgegory,shoe
3,Color,blue
3,Color,white
3,primarycolor,blue
5,size,M
5,Brand,Sports
5,Brand,Running
```

Python code in `un.py`:

```
# up.py
#
import csv
rowid={};  colid={};  tab={};  rowTitle=[];  colTitle=[]
with open('list.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
  v = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in v:
    rowid[row[0]]=1;  colid[row[1]]=1;  k=row[0]+"@"+row[1]
    if tab.has_key(k):
      tab[k]=tab[k]+"/"+row[2]        
    else:
      tab[k]=row[2]

rowTitle=rowid.keys(); colTitle=colid.keys()
rowTitle.sort();  colTitle.sort();

s=""
for j in colTitle: s=s+","+j 
print s
for i in rowTitle:
  s=i
  for j in colTitle:
    k=i+"@"+j
    s=s+","
    if tab.has_key(k):
      s=s+tab[k]  
  print s
```

`py un.py` output is:

```
,Brand,Color,Fits,Gender,Logo,catgegory,primarycolor,size,width
1,sports,White,,Male,yes,,,,10
3,,blue/white,,,,shoe,blue,,
4,Running,,Lose,,,,,,12
5,Sports/Running,,,,,,,M,
```